# Performance issues on a MySQL database with 150 million rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb, performance, performance-tuning

Current setup:

- A managed vps server
- InnoDB storage for big tables
- 10.0.36-MariaDB
- 18gb ram
- 8 x 2.40 GHz CPU.

I have a pretty big MariaDB database table which is used for Business intelligence analytics data. The current table data fluctuates from 150-180 million rows depending on data that is being imported.

The database is filled through a java file that was custom written, and the data is being read through a custom PHP api, through a method that uses the table indexes. The data is date separated and currently the table holds around 2-3 years of data.

My problem is that whenever we see an error with the data we usually need to re-import large volumes of data going back a long time. Meaning tens of thousands of report files that each is being consumed by the java file and imported one by one.

I've done some speed optimisation to the import process, and a single report doesn't take long, unless the report is 300mb or so - then it takes around 10-15 minutes depending on the busyness of the database at that moment.

The daily report import usually has 200-400 files and it takes an hour in the early morning when no-ones in the office. It's all ran by cronjobs and custom report downloading scripts from various sources.

The daily imports and data fetches are pretty fast - however when one wants to make let's say a years data fetch where every day would be visible in the graph for one metric - it can take 10-15 minutes or longer if multiple people are trying to do the same, or if something big is being imported

The data that is being fetched is not a single query, I separate every day as a separate request - that sped up the fetches 10 times or more, depending on how long the time period is.

In a perfect world I'd like to optimize the structure or any settings I could so I could import the data faster and fetch longer timeframe data faster. Our current approach is to have a single database separated for analytics data, with a couple of helper tables.

What kind of optimisation could I do for this amount of data, knowing that we grow around 5-8 million rows per month (that could increase)?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

- `INSERTing` one row at a time can be sped up by gathering 100 rows and inserting them in a single batch:  `INSERT INTO t (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3), (11,22,33), ...`  This may speed up things by a factor of 10.
- Check for errors after each batch.  If the batch fails, write it to a file for fixing and re-importing.  (This should improve the error-handling pass.)
- Assuming the data is only "new" data, it should be easy to summarize the data for each day and write this to a new table.  This may speed up fetching a years's data for graphing by 10x.
- The daily 200-400 files might be handled by multiple processes.  Suggest not breaking it into more processes than you have CPUs.

Putting all those together might shrink the elapsed time from hours to minutes.

If you would like to discuss things further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and maybe some more details on the data and its processing.  What's the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: we're already optimising by importing multiple  lines. The problem is that there is a unique key where on each insert statement the on duplicate clause must be executed.

I will improve the error handling
Not only new data is imported, there are often cases where older data is re-imported, and some reports only provide data for the whole month, so I delete the whole months data and re-import it.

Process meaning launching multile instances of import?

Comment: If you want to discuss further, please provide the SQL for a sample run.

Answer (score -3):

You can perform a couple of optimization techniques before importing data that might reduce the overall processing time like disabling the indexes temporarily or partitioning the table. But all these solutions might not be able to solve a big problem which is what happens when the data grows further and you need to upgrade your server and hardware infrastructure? Keeping this in mind, any other cloud database solution such as SingleStore would be helpful for your need which provides services on the pay-as-you-go model and is relatively faster than MySQL. Also, you don't need to worry about scaling out since it handles it on its own.